# AceSEF exclude urls from creation/ hide in sitemap

Tags: extensions, sef

I manage a large site which uses a number of Joomla articles as content snippets, ie. they are embedded into other articles, mainly for the purpose of re-use. This embedding is done via jSeblod CCK.

However, naturally AceSEF creates URLs for these pages and also creates sitemap entries.

Are there ways to either
- not create these AceSEF entries
- unpublish them from the sitemap?

Versions are:
- Joomla 3.3.0
- jSeblod 3.3.5
- AceSEF 4.1.0

Comment: What are you using to generate the site map? I ask because xmap usually goes off menu items, not raw article urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the slow response. I found that there are two ways to exclude items from both AceSEF urls and Sitemap and there is a further way to hide sitemap entries:

1. Exclude whole components from AceSEF:

In AceSEF-> Extensions, set the Router to "Disable SEF"

[image: Screenshot of AceSEF extensions with Disable SEF]

2. Exclude categories from Content

For Content, if you click on the Extension name to edit the configuration, there is a field to select the categories to which SEF urls are applied, ie. this can be used for excluding whole categories from SEF url creation and therefore also sitemap generation

[image: Screenshot of AceSEF content extension, category selection field]

3. Exclude single items from Sitemap

On top of the previous methods, which stop the creation of urls in the first place, sitemap entries can be manually unpublished. To do this go to AceSEF->Sitemap and unpublish the entries as needed

[image: Screenshot of AceSEF Sitemap screen with publish/ unpublish butttons highlighted]

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with AceSEF, so I have no idea about its capabilities features and such.
I guess what you want is to not add those urls of the snippets items in the sitemap, since they are not actually pages.
If the sitemap creation feature does not provide a way to exclude items/urls from the sitemap, then one possible way to achieve this would be to override this feature.

Unfortunately I have no access to the component, therefore it is impossible to speak specifically about what you have to change on the component. 
But you could dig into the extension's sitemap creation code and find out more about how it is being handled.

A possible approach could be the following:
You could create a specific category called "Snippets", and then you could exclude all its items from appearing in the view part of the sitemap. It is possible that this exclusion must happen at a helper file, which might query the database for items, or inside a jSeblod - AceSEF plugin.

This is how I would started, in conjunction with a question to the AceSEF developers to find out more about the AceSEF's approach.